Setting tabindex dynamically in a navigation drawer
I'm trying to ignore the focus when the drawer is closed, but I still can tab through links, even when it's closed (when showDrawer ref is set to false). I can even still tab if I set tabindex="-1" on the <nav>. The only solution I found is to add :tabindex="showDrawer ? 0 : -1" directly to each of the <router-link> or a <button>, not even the <li>, but the actual element inside of it, otherwise it won't work. I feel like it's not the best way to do it. I need to somehow manage to do it using tabindex, because removing the drawer from the DOM when it's closed is going to add performance implications.
<template>
    <nav class="drawer" :tabindex="showDrawer ? 0 : -1">
        <ul class="drawer__list">
            <li class="drawer__item">
                <router-link
                    to="/"
                    >Home</router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="drawer__item">
                <button
                    About
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="drawer__item">
                <button
                    Log In
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ItemOverlay :class="{ active: showDrawer }" />
</template>

Looking for a possible solution.

use v-show instead of v-if.  this will use display: none to hide the nav instead of completely removing it from the DOM.  This should still work at preventing focus when tabbing.

@yoduh but the transition won't work then. I want to keep the drawer hiding/unhiding animation.

You also can use @keyframes to switch to display: none at the end of a CSS transition

It’s great that you are starting to consider keyboard interaction for accessibility! I hope I can clarify two misunderstandings that you currently seem to have.

tabindex is not inherited in the DOM, it only applies to the element itself
Focus order is not the only thing to worry about when hiding a (navigation) drawer, general access by assistive technology must also be prohibited

This can be done with the inert attribute:
<nav class="drawer" :inert="!showDrawer">

That is if you can’t use CSS that reliably hides the element from interaction and assistive technology like display: none or visibility: hidden.


<p><a href="#">First tab stop</a></p>

<nav inert>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" current="page">Active Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p><a href="#">Last tab stop</a></p>



The alternative would be to hide the navigation from assistive technology
<nav class="drawer" :aria-hidden="!showDrawer">

and avoid focus for each interactive element
<router-link :tabindex="showDrawer ? 0 : -1"…

inert does both of these.

I’m currently having some difficulty testing if tabindex gets respecte by router-link. Any help is appreciated.

The inert worked, thank you! So simple. I've also found out that this attribute won't work if I set it on <ItemDrawer/>, which is a component that is inside of <AppHeader> (Drawer is a part of a header in my case). So, I'd have to go to <ItemDrawer/> first and then add inert on the <nav> there.

just checked again. inert only worked by preventing the user from clicking/focusing, but I still can access both  and the  in the <nav><ul><li>button or router-link<li/><ul/><nav/> with voice assistant. I'm using Edge and it's built-in voice assistant.

It only works as expected if I add both inert and aria-hidden on the <nav>.

That’s weird, inert should be supported in Edge since version 102. According to a11ysupport it work in Edge. But I’m unfamiliar with the integrated voice assistant.

so in Edge, if I right-click on the header and click on 'Read aloud' option, it starts from the logo and then reads the links on the hidden drawer, until I add :aria-hidden="!showDrawer". But if I use any other screen reader and just tab, because I set inert it works fine. I think the safest bet is to use both inert and aria-hidden to support all browsers. It's anyways a shorter way, rather than adding tabindex to each link, which is too much duplicates.
